# SQL Server 2017(Developer版）のサポート対象にWindows 10は含まれていますか？

Tags: windows-10, sql-server

Windows 10にSQL Server 2017（Developer版）をインストールして、スタンドアローン環境で開発したいと考えていますが、サポート対象かどうかわかりましたら教えてください。

また、Windows 10のため、SQL Server 2017をサーバ機能として提供するのはNGと考えておりますがこのあたりについてもご存知の方おしえてください。例えば、SQL Server 2017をインストールしたWidows 10端末をAとし、別のWindows 10端末をBとした場合、BからAのSQL Server にアクセスするのはNGという理解であっていますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

開発およびテストの目的ならば利用可能と思われます。

[SQL Server 2017 の各エディションとサポートされている機能](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15)

> **SQL Server エディション**　Developer
>   **定義**　開発者は、SQL Server Developer Edition を使用して、 SQL Server上で動作するあらゆる種類のアプリケーションを開発できます。 このエディションには Enterprise Edition の機能がすべて含まれていますが、**実稼動サーバーとして使用するのではなく、開発およびテスト システムとしての利用に対してライセンスが供与されます。 SQL Server Developer は、アプリケーションを作成し、テストするユーザーに適しています。**

[SQL Server の価格](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing)

> **SQL Server 2017 のエディション**　Developer
>   **最適な用途**　SQL Server ソフトウェアの完全機能版です。**開発者が SQL Server ソフトウェアを使ったアプリケーションを、優れたコスト効率で構築、テスト、実証できます。**
>   **ライセンス モデル**　ユーザーごと
>   **入手可能なチャネル**　無料ダウンロード
>   **Open レベルなし価格** (米国ドル)　無料

[SQL Server のインストールに必要なハードウェアおよびソフトウェア](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

> 32 ビット クライアント オペレーティング システムでサポートされている機能
>   **Windows 10 や Windows 8.1 など、Windows クライアント オペレーティング システムは 32 ビットまたは 64 ビットのアーキテクチャとして利用できます。 すべての SQL Server 機能は 64 ビット クライアント オペレーティング システムでサポートされています。** サポートされている 32 ビット クライアント オペレーティング システムでは、マイクロソフトは次の機能をサポートします。

[SQL Server 2017を無料で使用する方法](https://sql-oracle.com/sqlserver/?p=1394)

> テスト環境・開発環境
>   開発・テスト・学習用では無料で使用できます。
>   客先と同じ環境を用意したり、テスト的に試す場合など、開発者にとってSQL Serverはありがたいライセンスになっています。