# SQL Server 2017 のインストール可能なサーバについて

Tags: windows, windows-10, sql-server

SQL Server 2017 Standard を以下要件に合わせてWindows 10 に導入を予定しているのですが、プロセッサーがCore i7（インテル® Core™ i5-7200Uプロセッサー）のマシンへインストールした場合、それは動作がサポートされますでしょうか？

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: どういった懸念があり、どのような回答を求められているのでしょうか？ 「サポート」という言葉にどのような内容を求められているかにも変わってくると思います。

Comment: タイトルと本文の説明が微妙にかみ合ってない印象です (プロセッサの話をしているのか、サーバOSの話をしているのか) 。また、あくまで Windows 10 はクライアント向けOSなはずですので、サーバ用途での利用を検討しているならライセンスも絡んでくるので注意が必要かと思います。 - 参考: [一般向けWindowsはサーバー機能を提供してはダメ？ファイル共有はNG？](https://www.haruru29.net/blog/windows-share-files-20-devices/)

Comment: ここのサイトでも内容・条件は違いますがこの辺が類似の記事です。[SQL Server 2017をWindows 10のスタンドアロン環境で商用運用する場合どのエディションが適切でしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60345/26370), [SQL Server 2017(Developer版）のサポート対象にWindows 10は含まれていますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60319/26370)